# Segmentation fault (core dumped) on simple SQL code

Tags: c++, mysql, ubuntu

I get a “Segmentation fault (core dumped)” error on some simple C++ code. The error will accure when I use the variable result. What can cause this problem in this case? I know that something goes out of range, but how is it possible that result does? There are only 2 items in the database.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <mysql/mysql.h>
#include <mysql_connection.h>

using namespace std;

const char *server = "localhost";
const char *user = "XXXX";
const char *password = "XXXX";
const char *database = "XXXX";

int main()
{
    MYSQL *conn;
    MYSQL_RES *result;
    MYSQL_ROW row;

    int num_fields = 0;

    conn = mysql_init(NULL);
    mysql_real_connect(conn, server,user, password, database, 0, NULL, 0);

    mysql_query(conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` = '5'");
    result = mysql_store_result(conn);

    num_fields = mysql_num_fields(result);

    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)))
    {
       cout << "Spam ";
    }

    mysql_free_result(result);
    mysql_close(conn);
}
```

The error:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Process returned 139 (0x8B)   execution time : 0.255 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

Comment: My guess would be that either `mysql_init` or `mysql_real_connect` failed, so the following calls use incomplete objects/pointers. Try to debug that.

Comment: Added a if to determine if there is a problem there, they didn’t fail.

Comment: Thanks nos, I was missing "mysql.sock". Solved it with the command "sudo ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock". If you want you can add that as answer ;). This was a very stupid mistake. But why was it missing.

Comment: @Dagob You can answer to your own question if you have found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to make a symbolic link so that mysql can find mysql.sock:

```
sudo ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```